# No DOM, Use regex contain betwen tag div

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match

Not use DOM, i have content in tag div and i want get only string or string and tag  inside tag .

```
Ex:
1. <div>Lorem kid lasjdfdl asjf asdl f</div>// true
2. <div>Lorem <b>kid</b> lasjdfdl asjf asdl f</div>// true
3. <div>Lorem <div>kid</div> lasjdfdl asjf asdl f</div>// false
```

My regex code is `/<div>([^<]+)<\/div>/` but true for 1. I want true for 1 and 2.
Any one please help me, Thanks

Comment: What are your rules exactly? Why is 2 okay but 3 is not?

Comment: because, i want get content in tag div and some tag base as tag <b>,<a,<img

Comment: This belongs in Javascript

Comment: Why not replace? `s.replace(/^<div>|<\/div>$/g,'')`. Can you guarantee that the opening tag won't have attributes?

Comment: @Chris i need code regex, for this.. And i work on php :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Where is this DOM? Stored in a string on the server side? Or actual DOM on a page?

Comment: @RobG I want get content, not replace

Comment: @newbie_coder—the result is exactly what you want. Strings are immutable, **any** way you try to resolve this will result in a new string. *replace* is fast and less to type.

Comment: Answer of @Kerwin is exactly but i want cofirm tag <b> not tag <div>, because betwen tag <div> also have <div>,<table>,<p>.. etc. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJ5xA9/1)

```
^<div>(((?!<\/?div>).)*)<\/div>
```

Comment: Thanks @kerwin, this is best anser. But i want cofirm tag <b> not tag <div>... because betwen tag <div> also have <div>,<table>,<p>.. etc

Comment: do you mean just string or string with `<b>` is true,any string with other tag in `<div>` is false?

Comment: Yes, but fact in tag <div> not only tag div but also tag <table>, <p>, <video>.. etc so i want specify tag b

Comment: `^<div>([^<]|<\/?b>)+<\/div>$`  you can try this one

Comment: Thanks @kerwin, i try with tags <b> then oki.. why when i test with tag <a> then is not succes `^<div>([^<]|<\/?b|a>)+<\/div>$`